# Touchpad after-scroll delay fix?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, scrolling

I have an issue with my touchpad.
Every time I scroll, there's a 1sec (not sure) delay before the scrolling stops when I lift my fingers from the touchpad, and it will automatically zoom when I press control afterwards.
As a laptop user, I really want to switch tabs easily with ctrl tab etc...

For example, I'm on a webpage, I scroll all the way down, lift my fingers from the touchpad and I want to change tabs directly with ctrl+tab. The page than zooms in or out because I pressed control during the after-scroll delay...

Is there a way to disable this or is this a bug ? I don't think it's an issue with the touchpad sensitivity though.

Thanks

(using an Asus X751L)

Comment: Have you researched on Asus sites to see if this is a common thing?  Is it possible the machine is just suffering from lag?

Comment: @killermist this is a common issue on ASUS laptops

Answer (score 2):

I came across your question while facing the same issue on my Linux-powered laptop though I haven't found a hint of what OS you use.

If you use Linux, this info will be relevant to you. However, it was concluded that there is no way to implement a fix to this issue in the current X-server driver. There are some bug reports in different bug trackers:

- X-server - https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38909
- Chromium - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226947
- Ubuntu/FireFox - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/803348

The root cause is obviously in X-server and others report consequences. However, it is concluded that it is not fixable in current X-server driver. The only workaround is to disable or minimize inertial scrolling:

> Decreasing "CoastingSpeed" (i.e. to 5) limits the damage, but doesn't
>   seem to solve the problem.
>
> Increasing "CoastingFriction" does a better job, since it reduces the
>   amount of time in which the scrolling will continue. With a value of
>   200, problems are much more rare. It still find occasionally some
>   Firefox pages involuntarily zoomed out, when I scroll them then
>   Ctrl+PgUp to another tab, but not crazy levels.
>
> So resuming: 5 and 200-300 are optimal parameters, but the mechanism
>   is simply buggy, though I don't know at which level. Scrolling
>   "memory" should stop flowing when another key is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem on my Asus N552VW (and I think is a common problem for all the Asus computers) this way:

Go in `C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ASUS Smart Gesture\AsTPCenter\model\` and edit the file `InertiaSetting.ini` as Administrator.

Edit the field `MaxInertiaSeedDelta=100` to `MaxInertiaSeedDelta=0` and save.

Restart your computer (or Asus Smart Gesture) and enjoy.

At the beginning, the new behaviour seems weird and scrolling is not the same as before, but the annoying problem of zoom-in when doing anything regarding `CTRL` will be only an old, bad dream.

Comment: On my Asus UX305C this much improves the situation but doesn't completely solve it. There is now a subtle new bugged behaviour, where if I scroll and release both fingers while still in motion, the driver sends a single small 'scroll down' as an afterthought, even if I was scrolling up to begin with.